# Куда пропадает информация о типах аргументов в std::future? C++

Tags: c++

Набросал вот такой короткий [пример](https://godbolt.org/z/aj37qdcEs).

```
void increment(int *i)
{
    ++(*i);
}

template<typename Func, typename ...Args>
auto bar(Func &&task, Args&& ...args)
{
    return std::async(std::launch::deferred, std::forward<Func>(task),
                      std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    auto f = bar(&increment, &i);
    f.wait();
    std::cout << i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Здесь в `std::async` толкается функция типа `void(*int)`. При этом `async` возвращает `std::future<void>`. Но, получается, что если я в `std::async` толкну функция типа `void(*int, *char)`, то всё равно мне вернется `std::future<void>`.

Вопрос: куда девается информация об аргументах? `void(*int)` и `void(*int, *char)` - это ведь разные типы, почему они оба могут храниться в `std::future<void>`?

P.S. :
`void(*int)` и `void(*int, *char)` - разные типы. В таком случае как они могут храниться в одном типе `std::future<void>`? Как это может работать? Если внутри `std::future` лежит указатель на функцию типа `void(*int)`, то `void(*int, *char)` туда уже не положишь. Но оно кладется. Почему?

Comment: Не успел даже закрыть вкладку, а какой-то Флеш уже заминусовал тему :)

Comment: std::future предоставляет доступ к возвращаемому функцией значению. То есть тип шаблона std::future всегда равен типу возвращаемого значения.

Comment: @maestro спасибо за очевидное разъяснение, но я не об этом. void(*int) и void(*int, *char) - разные типы. В таком случае как они могут храниться в одном типе std::future<void>? Как это может работать? Если внутри std::future лежит указатель на функцию типа void(*int), то void(*int, *char) туда уже не положишь. Но оно кладется. Почему?

Comment: Ваш вопрос глубже, чем кажется на первый взгляд. Я не знаю точного ответа, хотя и имею догадки. Но для других отвечающих лучше добавьте ваши размышления из последнего комментария в вопрос, да и код тоже. Просто в таком виде их ответ будет таким же, как и мой комментарий.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/207294/

Comment: А они (типы функций) вообще в `future` хранятся? Там же вроде как только возвращаемое значение/исключение, а уж от чего оно пришло — дело десятое. Нет?

Answer (score 4):

> Если внутри std::future лежит указатель на функцию

А он там не лежит. Там лежит только указатель на память в куче, куда будет положено возвращаемое значение.

Вот вам самодельный игрушечный `async()`. Специально написанный плохо, без `forward` и прочего.

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename F, typename ...P>
auto my_async(F func, P ...params)
{
    using R = decltype(func(params...));
    std::promise<R> p;
    std::future<R> f = p.get_future();
    std::thread t([p = std::move(p), func, params...]() mutable
    {
        p.set_value(func(params...));
    });
    t.detach();
    return f;
}


int main()
{
    auto x = my_async([](int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }, 10, 20);
    std::cout << x.get() << '\n'; // 30
}
```

Comment: В таком случае как работает его метод wait()? Ведь если std::async вызывается с политикой deferred, то wait() выполнит функцию. Значит должен быть указатель на функцию...

Comment: @ComeInRage Хм, разумно. В таком случае представьте, что там `std::unique_ptr<Base>`, где у `class Base` есть `virtual R call() = 0;`, а наследник зашаблонен и может хранить в себе любой тип указателя на функцию и `tuple` с нужным аргументами. Возможно там что-то более умное, но общий смысл такой же.